# Getting undesired future date from converting unix timestamp

Tags: go

I have a unix timestamp :
`1607875199999`

I am trying to convert it to a date format:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    t := time.Unix(1607875199999,0)
    fmt.Println(t.Format("02/01/2006, 15:04:05"))
}
```

Result:
`15/07/52921, 15:59:59` : https://play.golang.org/p/eHx0IrQjL0o

When I check the same timestamp on: https://www.epochconverter.com/
It gives me: Sunday, 13 December 2020 15:59:59

Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: This is a millisecond timestamp, `time.Unix` expects a second timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
```

> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

You're passing the number of milliseconds since the begin of the epoch, not seconds. Split the timestamp into seconds and the fractional part:

```
var (
    millis  int64 = 1607875199999
    seconds       = millis / 1000
    nanos         = millis % 1000 * 1e6
)

t := time.Unix(seconds, nanos)
fmt.Println(t.Format("02/01/2006, 15:04:05.000")) // 13/12/2020, 15:59:59.999
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/hwz03bkd2Bq